# Why React Native is re-rendering all components of an array when it changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm making a chat app and displaying messages with a FlatList component or a simple map(), but when the array content changes, all items ares re-rendering, in React JS that not happend, why is it ?

UPDATE
This is how i do it in React JS, and works right, it is not re-rendering

```
const Chat = ({ roomid }) => {
  const messages = useSelector(state => state.chat.messages[roomid])
  ****more vars***
  useEffect(() => {
    if (refChat)
      refChat.current.scrollTop = refChat.current.scrollHeight
  }, [messages])
  return (
    <div id={"chat"} className="h-full c-grid-sm md:c-grid-md dark:bg-container bg-slate-800">
      <div className="h-full flex flex-col w-full bg-white dark:bg-container">
        <ScrollableDivVertical ref={refChat}>
          {messages && messages.map((m, i) => <Message key={i} canColors={canColors} fontSize={fontSize} scribbleSize={scribbleSize} user={m.user} customname={m.type === "publicmsg" && areswebsupport ?canColors ? users[m.userid]?.parsedcustomnamefc : users[m.userid]?.parsedcustomname:undefined} text={m.text} type={m.type} areswebsupport={areswebsupport} />)}
        </ScrollableDivVertical>
        <ChatInputText roomid={roomid} type={1} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default memo(Chat)
```

This is how i do it in React Native, and i'm having re-rendering.

```
const MessagesList = ({ navigate }) => {
  const messages = useSelector(state => state.chat.messages[roomid])
  ***other vars****
  const refMessagesList = useRef(null)
  
  return (
    <StyledView style={{ flex: 9 }} bg={isDark ? colors.gray : colors.light} fd="column" onTouchEnd={() => Keyboard.dismiss()}>
      <StyledView bg={isDark ? colors.dark : colors.blue} pb="5px" pt="5px" jc="center" ai="center" >
        <IconButton h='30px' w="10%" bg="transparent" icon="leftcircleo" onPress={() => navigate("OpenChats")} sizeIcon={30} colorIcon={colors.swhite} />
        <StyledView bg="transparent" w="90%">
          <StyledText fs="20px" ta="center" w="100%" fg={colors.swhite}>{roomname}</StyledText>
        </StyledView>
      </StyledView>
      <ScrollView ref={refMessagesList} onContentSizeChange={() => refMessagesList.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false })} style={{ backgroundColor: isDark ? colors.gray : colors.light, flex: 1, width: "100%" }} scrollsToTop={true}>
        {messages && messages.map((message, index) => (
          <MessageItem key={message.type ? message.type + index : "default" + index} k={message.type ? message.type + index : "default" + index} item={{ ...message, isDark, fontSize, scribbleSize, width, canColors }} customname={message.type === "publicmsg" && areswebsupport ? canColors ? users[message.userid]?.parsedcustomnamefc : users[message.userid]?.parsedcustomname : undefined} areswebsupport={areswebsupport} ></MessageItem>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </StyledView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React prevents unnecessary rerenders of children of a list using the `key` prop of the outer most parent component of each list item.

Make sure you have set this prop to each children in the list and it's a unique value for each child.

Furthermore if you are not using a vanilla `html` (`<div key={"id_1"}>`)/`react-native` (`<View key={"id_1"}>`) component make sure the `key` prop gets forwarded to the first proper vanilla component. If this is not the case the `key` prop is not used and has no effect.

Here is an example on snack.expo.dev => https://snack.expo.dev/rX7ctIwTJ

```js
export default function App() {
  const randomValues = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <View>
      {randomValues.map((value, indexOfValueInArray) => (
        <View key={'child_' + indexOfValueInArray}>
          <Text>{value}</Text>
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Read more about the `key` prop here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I've checked and i have unique key props... I added code to explain.

Comment: The problem was another reason, but the key prop was very useful too.